# creating a sliding widget with bootstrap and mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a sliding widget a sliding widget with bootstrap and MySQL with PHP. On the widget, I am able to display only one (the first) record out of the 8 in the database.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

```
<div class="widget widget-default widget-carousel">
    <div class="owl-carousel" id="owl-example">
        <div>
            <?php
            $query = "SELECT wlt_name as wltname,max(DATE_FORMAT(wlt_txn_date,'%d-%b-%Y')) as lastdate, truncate (sum(IF(wlt_txn_type = 'Expense', -wlt_txn_amount, wlt_txn_amount)),2) AS netamount from wallet_txns WHERE  wlt_txn_id > 0 and wlt_holder_id = 1 group by wlt_name limit 10";
            $res = mysqli_query($bd, $query);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($res);
            $slides = '';
            $counter = 0;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $title = $row['wltname'];
                $desc = $row['lastdate'];
                $image = $row['netamount'];
                if ($counter == 0) 
                {
                    $slides .= '
                        <h3>' . $title . '</h3>
                        <p>' . $desc . '.</p>  
                        <p>' . $image . '.</p>';
                }
                    $counter++;
            }
            ?>
        </div>                               
        <div class="widget-subtitle"> <?php echo $slides; ?></div>
    </div>                            
    <div class="widget-controls">                                
        <a href="#" class="widget-control-right widget-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Remove Widget"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></a>
    </div>                             
</div>
```

Comment: So what is the question? You want to display all 8 records or what?

Comment: @brance Sorry for the delayed reply. Yes, need to display 8 records. Sliding one by one.